# selecting data as groups from table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, db2

I have a table (Primary key as the combination of `ID`, `COLUMN A` and `COLUMN B`) with the following data:

```
 +---------+------------+------------+-----------+
 |   ID    |  COLUMN A  |  COLUMN B  |  COLUMN C |
 +---------+------------+------------+-----------+
 |   1     |    A1      |    B1      |    C1     |
 |   2     |    A2      |    B2      |    C2     |
 |   3     |    A1      |    B1      |    C3     |
 |   4     |    A3      |    B3      |    C1     |
 |   5     |    A1      |    B1      |    C3     |
 +-----------------------------------------------+
```

I want data fetched as:

```
 +---------+------------+------------+-----------+
 |   ID    |  COLUMN A  |  COLUMN B  |  COLUMN C |
 +---------+------------+------------+-----------+
 |   2     |    A2      |    B2      |    C2     |
 |   4     |    A3      |    B3      |    C1     |
 |   5     |    A1      |    B1      |    C3     |
 +-----------------------------------------------+
```

Should I be using this:

```
  SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
  GROUP BY 
  COLUMN A, COLUMN B
  ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: I don't understand the logic/rules behind your expected result set.  Can you explain it here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want the rows in the `column A` and `column B` with same data to be grouped together then I want to fetch the row with `max(ID)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is way to do this without using window functions, assuming you might be using an older version of MySQL:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.A, t1.B, t1.C
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT A, B, MAX(ID) AS MAX_ID
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY A, B
) t2
    ON t1.A = t2.A AND t1.B = t2.B AND t1.ID = t2.MAX_ID
ORDER BY
    t1.ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using window function where you can use `max`. here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3TGBWSSaSwj2THvk5qxYbF/0).

```
select
    max(ID) as ID,
    columnA,
    columnB,
    max(columnC) as columnC
from myTable
group by    
    columnA,
    columnB
order by    
    ID
```

You can use window function `row_number`, Here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8zRUkjzmuv7NjHnMh3Myob/0).

```
select
  ID,
  columnA,
  columnB,
  columnC
from
(
  select
    *,
    row_number() over (partition by columnA, columnB order by ID desc) as rn
  from yourTable
) subq
where rn = 1
```

output:

```
| ID  | columnA | columnB | columnC |
| --- | ------- | ------- | ------- |
| 2   | A2      | B2      | C2      |
| 4   | A3      | B3      | C1      |
| 5   | A1      | B1      | C3      |
```